# Open CMD as Administrator

Tags: automationanywhere

is it possible to launch CMD as administrator? 
I tried keystrokes

```
WINDOWNN x a WINUP
WINDOWN r WINUP cmd CONTROLDOWN SHIFTDOWN ENTER
```

All without Success. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks, Luka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the Windows button. Type CMD then Press CTRL + Shift + Enter.

Comment: This worked thank you !! My issue is that even though i release the shift and control in AA, it doesnt reflect on the desktop

Comment: [CTRL UP][SHIFT UP]

Comment: Also, I am unable to send any "Keystrokes" to the CMD even though i enter the window name correctly - "Administrator: Command Prompt"

Comment: Use the on-screen keyboard.